# Windows Batch file + console exe

Tags: batch-file, console, exe

I've been trying to create a batch file that passes text to a console application. In this case its an exe that trims a large .dat file to the start/stop time and date specified. It expects the file name, start, stop, and a y(es) response to start the cut. The script below works, but after submitting the final "y" response, the .exe terminates without even attempting to start the cut.

Can anyone see what could be wrong? Tried ping delays, pause, /wait - all to the same effect.

```
@echo Off

Set program=c:\rtdm_cutter.exe

(
echo 20121126_191613_09224_RTDM.BIN 
echo 2012/11/25 15:00:00
echo 2012/11/25 15:15:00
echo y
) |start /realtime /B /wait %program%
```

Comment: To understand the environment a little more.  Where are each of the .bin, .exe, and .bat files in relation to each other?  This is to solve if the .exe is finding the .bin file.  Next, is the .exe outputting any messages after sending it the 'y'?

Comment: the console exe itself, rtdm_cutter.exe is sensitive, any mistakes to the file names or time parameters and it will exit immediately. Its job is to trim the RTDM.BIN file (~4gb) to a smaller size (smaller timeframe). So, what is happening is, the bat file as it is above is launching the rtdm_cutter.exe, and it is accepting all the piped in inputs, but is ending after the final yes instead of producing the cut. Here is a screenshot of where it stops: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20659655/Cut.JPG Despite the /wait, it closes immediately.

Comment: and yes, the bin file is being found, or it would not proceed to accepting the start time.

Comment: made some headway. By adding "&& more" to the end of "echo 2012/11/25 15:15:00" gives me a chance to manually enter the y (yes) and the cut starts correctly. It would be perfect if I could get it to auto accept the Y and continue.

Comment: Since the more option works it would seem that it is indeed a timing issue.  The reason that I do not see a ping delay working is that it would be evaluated and elapse before the start command is called.  The script would process all of the commands within the parentheses before directing the output to the start command.  The more however works, because it acts as an interrupt in the output.

Comment: Is there any known or noticeable delay from when the second time stamp is entered util it prompts for the yes/no?

Comment: No, instantaneously asks yes/no. The way it is now, it performs the task to 100% but hangs there until ctrl c or closing window. The script does not ever progress.

Comment: Add the following (unquoted) to the beginning of the line with "&& more" to automatically accept whatever answer you want by piping it: "echo y |" Remember to remove the quotes, and put those characters in the very beginning of the line in question.

Comment: Have you tried using a file as input? You could pipe the "commands" to a file first. Also, you might try something crazy like adding an extra newline (echo.) before the confirmation.
Do you have access to the source code for the .EXE? The method it's using to get the confirmation would be useful to know.

Answer (score 0):

I would write the script differently, similar to this:

```
@echo off  
:: script.bat  
SET programx=c:\rtdm_cutter.exe
IF "%1"=="" ( SET one=20121126_191613_09224_RTDM.BIN ) ELSE ( SET one=%1 )
IF "%1"=="" ( SET two=2012/11/25 15:00:00 ) ELSE ( SET one=%2 )
IF "%1"=="" ( SET thr=2012/11/25 15:15:00 ) ELSE ( SET one=%3 )
IF "%1"=="" ( SET answer=Y ) ELSE ( SET answer=%4 )
IF "%4"=="" ECHO %answer% | start /realtime /B /wait %programx% %one% %two% %thr%
IF "%4"=="" GOTO :END    
ECHO %answer% | cmd.exe /C %programx% %1 %2 %3    
:END
pause
```

Then, call it like so (as an example):

```
CALL .\script.bat blah.BIN "2012/11/25 15:00:00" "" "Y"
```

No guarantee this code will work. I am guessing.  But hopefully you get the idea.